# How to write variable value with remapped key from vimrc function to command prompt in vim?

Tags: text-processing, vim

This is the function which call xkb-switch util to remap any one pressed cyrillic key and on the next line is the trigger for the func:

```
function!
  RestoreKeyboardLayout(key)
  call system('xkb-switch -s us')
  execute 'normal! ' . a:key
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> й :call RestoreKeyboardLayout('q')<CR>
```

However, this would attempt to "execute" `q`, which is not what I want. I want to insert the character `q` at my vim prompt instead.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do here? Are you trying to make `:й` work the same as `:q` so that you can quit Vim with a Cyrillic key layout? (You don't really need to switch X keyboard layout for that...)

Comment: Not quite. I need to open command prompt with evaluated 'q'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "open command prompt"... Do you mean the [`Q`](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#Q) command to enter Ex mode, with the `:` prompt?

Comment: Yes. I know that it is possible to bind one letter 'й' but not with a <C> modifier key unfortunately. This auto substitute by xkb-switch allows to do that but only immediately, without manual <CR> by 'Enter' button.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish... Also, what do you mean by "command prompt" here? I really can't tell... Can you describe as plainly as possible what you want to happen when you press the `й` key in Normal mode?

Comment: I need to press <C-й> to get :q at bottom of vim window.

Comment: Why not just `:nnoremap й :q`? That will enter the prompt and leave a `:q` command waiting for return... I really don't follow the thing with the keyboard layout switch and the Control modifier... In any case, if you need to switch, would `nnoremap й :call system('xkb-switch -s us')<CR>:q` work? You mentioned "variable value" as in an argument to the function... Does it *need* to be an argument?